# How to Add New custom button of Import template in my grid?

Tags: magento-1.9

i have an button add item now i want to add import template button but when i used same helper it override previous button..so how can I create multiple button there ??

my module

```
<?php
class Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Web extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_web';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'web';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('web')->__('Matrid FeedManager');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('web')->__('Create new Template');


    parent::__construct();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple problem. Use the following code, You can add two buttons in admin grid.

Updated answer :-

```
<?php
class Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Web extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_web';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'web';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('web')->__('Matrid FeedManager');
    $this->_addButton('new', array(
        'label'   => Mage::helper('web')->__('Add Item'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new')}')",
        'class'   => 'add'
    ));
    $this->_addButton('import', array(
        'label'   => Mage::helper('web')->__('Create new Template'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/import')}')",
        'class'   => 'add'
    ));
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
  }

}
```

In your controller,write action for **Create new Teamplate** button.

```
 public function importAction()
 {
   /*  do what you want */
 }
```

Let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: thx u so much its working but i want import button after matrid feedmanager button ..

Comment: I have updated my answer,check.. It will put import button after matrid feedmanager button.

Comment: i m working on edit from can u tell me how to add a simple keyword like column in edit from??? not input box only static keyword

Comment: Edit from or edit form.?

Comment: edit form i mean in which i want to add  a text between form only not input text just show like a heading ? after click on module create template it open a edit form in which m saying

Comment: are u asking like this.`$fieldset->addField('header_note', 'note', array(
       'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('General Instructions : '),
          'text'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('<b>Uploading CSV File Should Contains 10 Columns.</b><br/>'),
        ));`

Comment: something like this but i dont want general instruction title  then after space i want two words only uploading  &   contains then  a button below that .when any one click on that it will appear two input box. in next line  .

Comment: check this link image ..column and pattern   as like that 

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=data+feed+manager+configuration+edit+form+images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ8-iB6vrZAhVMpY8KHdNoAnAQ_AUICigB&biw=1600&bih=794#imgrc=d_6xoGnWRzrpsM: